# Python passing variable tuples between functions

Tags: python, function, variables

Im having an issue with returning multiple values in a fuction and using them in a different function. For simplicity:

```
def menu1():
    system=system1
    choice=1
    return system,choice
 def menu2():
    option = menu1() #this assigns the option a tuple based on the first function.
    if option==system1:
        print"yes"
    if option==1:
        print"yes"


menu2()
```

How can i correctly give option a value of either "system1" or "1" based on getting the values from a previous function?

Comment: If you only want to assign one value to option then return only one value from menu1 based on some condition..

Comment: not sure what you want but `option = menu1()` will return a tuple with two variables. so your `option == system` or `option ==1` will not be True

Comment: use `system, choice = menu1()`, the tuple will be unpacked automatically

Comment: @avinash pandey this makes sense, but I need both of these return values. for example i need something like option1 = menu1(system1 value) and option2 = menu("1" value)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can index the tuple just as you would any other kind of sequence:

```
 def menu2():
    option = menu1()
    if option[0]==system1:
        print"yes"
    if option[1]==1:
        print"yes"
```

Sequences are 0-indexed in Python so the first element is at index 0, and the second is at index 1, and so on.

However, in my opinion, it's clearer to do the following:

```
 def menu2():
    system, choice = menu1()
    if system==system1:
        print"yes"
    if choice==1:
        print"yes"
```

This is called tuple-unpacking and it can be used to split the value of a tuple up into multiple names to be assigned to.